# 500 Internal Server Error returned instead of: 404 - Not Found

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I am getting 500 Internal Server Error instead of: 404 - Not Found whenever I type a non-existent page address for my site.

My best guess it has something to do with my .htaccess settings:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA] 

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

My .htaccess checks and redirects all the urls to `https://www.` form. It also takes care of hiding .php extensions from the all of the pages.

It took me a long time to come up with above code and now I am really afraid to change anything since I am not really good with .htaccess syntax.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: @anubhava Yes it does

Comment: @Acidon I think it is because of this rule `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]` which says that if the requested URI is neither a file nor a directory, then go to `$1.php` which matches the first group. It tried to find and didn't get, so probably a 500 server error, because you can't have dynamic files like that according to request URI. Did you check the logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your 2 redirect rules must be combined into one to avoid multiple `301` redirects (bad for SEO and efficiency)
2. You must check for presence of `.php` file before adding `.php` in your URI.
3. Avoid hardcoding host name in your rule.

**Full .htaccess:**

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteEngine On

## add www and turn on https in same rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

# if not a directory and .php file is present then add .php extension
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Now typing non existent page instead of giving 500 error redirects me to home page. It needs to go to 404.php

Comment: As you can see, no where these rules are invoking your home page or `index.php` so it must be something in your code. To test further change first line to `ErrorDocument 404 default` and retest.

Comment: Ahh, you are correct, there were some additional strings on the bottom that caused this, it is working great now, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After these tow lines :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Add this line :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
```

to make sure that request accept `php` extension before sending to it :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L,QSA]
```

When you send non-existing requests to any target make sure that target will manage this issue properly otherwise server will give error .